# android nested layout_weights

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to have the effect of LinearLayout Horizontal inside LinearLayout Vertical. The problem is I want to have layout_weights for Views in the Horizontal layout and layout_weights for the Views in the Vertical one. It works, but in eclipse I get a warning that it's inefficient and that I shouldn't use layout_weights one in another.

---

This is what I did:

[image: LinearLayout inside LinearLayout]

In the horizontal LinearLayout each button got a layout_weight of 1 and in the vertical LinearLayout, each inner View got a certain weight as well.

Is there a way to do this effect in some other way and keep it flexible to look good in all the devices? I don't plan on using GridLayout because I want to support older devices running android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a warning. If you will not continue to wrap the `LinearLayout` in another one with `weigths` and so on, maybe you can ignore this warning. Using `layout_weight` is bad for performance because AFAIK it will cause each `widget` to be measured twice, than each `widget` inside it to be measured again twice and so on.

If you do not see performance issues with your layout, I think you can keep it, because I can`t see other ways to achieve this.

Alternatively, there is also a backward compatible [`GridLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html) if you want to consider using it.